# Выдает неверный результат при окончании работы

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
 
 
def display_full_name():
    messagebox.showinfo("Итоговая сумму", st)
 
root = Tk()
root.title("Определение стоимости звонка")
 
name = IntVar()
surname = IntVar()
st = IntVar()
name_label = Label(text="Введите код города:")
surname_label = Label(text="Введите длительность разговора:")
 
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
surname_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
 
name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
surname_entry = Entry(textvariable=surname)
 
name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
surname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
if name == 343:
     st == 15*surname
elif name == 381:
     st == 18*surname
elif name == 473:
     st == 13*surname
elif name == 48:
     st == 11*surname
 
message_button = Button(text="Рассчитать", command=display_full_name)
message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
 

root.mainloop()
```

После введения значений , код выдает PY_VAR2, а должен значение st

Answer (score 1):

Куча ошибок...
Считаете до того как ввели значения.
Обращаетесь к tk-переменным напрямую, а не через метод `get()`.
`==` вместо `=` при присваивании.
tk-переменная `st` перезаписывается обычной питоновской.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
 
def display_full_code():
    price = {343: 15, 381: 18, 473: 13, 48: 11}
    code_val = code.get()
    duration_val = duration.get()
    if code_val in price:
        st = price[code_val] * duration_val
    else:
        st = f"Код города `{code_val}` не поддерживается."
    messagebox.showinfo("Итоговая сумма", st)
 
root = Tk()
root.title("Определение стоимости звонка")
 
code = IntVar()
duration = IntVar()
code_label     = Label(text="Введите код города:")
duration_label = Label(text="Введите длительность разговора:")
 
code_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
duration_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
 
code_entry     = Entry(textvariable=code)
duration_entry = Entry(textvariable=duration)
 
code_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
duration_entry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
 
message_button = Button(text="Рассчитать", command=display_full_code)
message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
 
root.mainloop()
```